# Do I have to write catch error in all script when fetching data from server?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I got some question about try, catch of data that is thrown from server using await.

for example

script A

```
try{
  let a = await get_user_data()
}
catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
```

script B

```
try{
  let b = await get_something()
}
catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
```

Let's just see we have a code like this to get user data, and another script to get something from the server.
If the user token is expired, the two scripts will get 401 error(Logged in is required) and If no action is made, it will just end with it.

So here's my question. Do I have to write all codes on each scripts to do some actions? like if error.respond.status is 401 go to login page, if error.respond.status is 500 do something...
Is there a better way to know the error has occured in App(.svelte)? or something like global error variable?

Comment: Are you using sveltekit?

Comment: no just svelte not svelte kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to use a try catch. But it makes sense to implement error handling. If you have a try catch for every api call, I would take a different approach. I would write a function that does the XHR. You give the function only the endpoint, method and data. In this method you can do the error handling once. This way you would have it centrally in one place for all XHR calls with one error handling.